# can't attach row and col names into a dataframe in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `matrix` with `31053` obs and `4909` variables. I have two separate dataframes, `barcodes.tsv` and `featurescorrected` with `4909` and `31053` rows, respectively, which are the row and col names of this dataframe. I am trying to attach them with the following

```
barcodes.tsv <- t(barcodes.tsv)
row.names(matrix) = featurescorrected
col.names(matrix) = barcodes.tsv
```

But I get these two errors

```
Error in `.rowNamesDF<-`(x, value = value) : invalid 'row.names' length
> col.names(matrix) = barcodes.tsv
Error in col.names(matrix) = barcodes.tsv : 
  could not find function "col.names<-"
```

I don't understand how the length is not correct, as it has the exact same value as my dataframe. I also don't get why the col.names function is not found, as far as I know this is not from a package or anything like it

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: it's `colnames` not `col.names`. For the row.names, can't comment without seeing the data, but check the dimensions of both.

Answer (score 0):

As @AdroMine said in the comments, your `col.names` function needs to be `colnames`. You can use this code:

```
barcodes.tsv <- t(barcodes.tsv)
row.names(matrix) = featurescorrected
colnames(matrix) = barcodes.tsv
```